# Find Average of data to two precision decimal places

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get the average of the sample data to two decimal position

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Nos INT, Months VARCHAR(20), Duration INT)
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
(1,'Jan',33),(1,'Jan',107),(1,'Jan',36),(1,'Jan',139),(1,'Jan',140),(1,'Jan',5),(1,'Jan',130),
(1,'Jan',176),(1,'Jan',30),(2,'Feb',39),(2,'Feb',62),(2,'Feb',76),(2,'Feb',115),(2,'Feb',101),
(2,'Feb',12),(2,'Feb',139),(2,'Feb',174),(3,'Mar',5),(3,'Mar',59),(3,'Mar',72),(3,'Mar',100),(3,'Mar',153);
```

My query

```
SELECT
Nos,    
Months, 
AVG(Duration) AS [Average of Duration]
FROM @TBL
GROUP BY Nos,Months
ORDER BY Nos
```

Current output

```
Nos Months  Average of Duration
1    Jan      88
2    Feb      89
3    Mar      77
```

Expected Output

```
No  Month   Average of Duration
1    Jan      88.44
2    Feb      89.75
3    Mar      77.80
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (Nos INT, Months VARCHAR(20), Duration INT)
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
(1,'Jan',33),(1,'Jan',107),(1,'Jan',36),(1,'Jan',139),(1,'Jan',140),(1,'Jan',5),(1,'Jan',130),
(1,'Jan',176),(1,'Jan',30),(2,'Feb',39),(2,'Feb',62),(2,'Feb',76),(2,'Feb',115),(2,'Feb',101),
(2,'Feb',12),(2,'Feb',139),(2,'Feb',174),(3,'Mar',5),(3,'Mar',59),(3,'Mar',72),(3,'Mar',100),(3,'Mar',153);

SELECT
Nos,    
Months, 
CAST(AVG(1.0 * Duration) AS DECIMAL(4, 2)) AS [Average of Duration]
FROM @TBL
GROUP BY Nos,Months
ORDER BY Nos;
```

Results:

```
+-----+--------+---------------------+
| Nos | Months | Average of Duration |
+-----+--------+---------------------+
|   1 | Jan    |               88.44 |
|   2 | Feb    |               89.75 |
|   3 | Mar    |               77.80 |
+-----+--------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add explicit arithmetic with `avg` :

```
SELECT Nos, Months, AVG(1.0 * Duration) AS [Average of Duration]
FROM @TBL
GROUP BY Nos, Months
ORDER BY Nos;
```